# Basic VR information about its axis orientation

Tags: virtual-reality, webvr, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality, fieldofview

I have just started working with FOVE VR headset. I am having things working fine with Visual Studio - C#. However, I was interested to know where is the origin of the axis for all the VRs. In the other words, the eye position vector is relative to what ?

Also, what unit is the eye position values are displayed on the Debug tools. I am interested in these details since I need to align VR axis with Leap Motion axis which is a hand tracker and integrate it to use with another application.

Your help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- The origin of the axis for all the VR headsets is between the two eyes.
- The values displayed in the Debug tool are **not** eye position values, rather they are normalized unit directional vectors. So, you should be able to observe that *x^2+y^2+z^2* is equal or almost equal to 1. Any values slightly above or below 1 are due to floating point precision.